# Reduce array of json to json object

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have details as

```
data = {
  name: "charles",
  id: "1",
  education: [
    {"class": "X","marks": 223,"percentage": "59%"},
    {"class": "IX","marks": 223,"percentage": "59%"},
    {"class": "IIX","marks": 223,"percentage": "59%"},
    {"class": "IIIX","marks": 223,"percentage": "59%"}
  ]
}
```

My desired result need is to break into 4 json objects

```
{name:"charles",id:"1", education:{"class":"X","marks":223,"percentage":59%}}
{name:"charles",id:"1", education:{"class":"IX","marks":223,"percentage":59%}}
```

Can anyone let me know how to achieve it?

I am sucessfully by looping and creating each object induvidually as follows:

```
this.data.education.forEach( class => {
        const newData: any = {};
        newData.name= data.name;
        newData.id= data.id;
        newData.education = class ;
array.push(newData);
});

I am looking for any simplist way of achieving it?
```

Comment: There is NO JSON in the question as JSON is a text serialization format. The shown code is ‘JavaScript’ (and Object Literal syntax). See http://json.org, and update the title / tags / wording appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract name and id and pass along all entries of education array. Hope this helps

```js
const data = { name: "charles", id: "1", education: [
    { "class": "X", "marks": 223, "percentage": 59 },
    { "class": "IX", "marks": 223, "percentage": 59 },
    { "class": "IIX", "marks": 223, "percentage": 59 },
    { "class": "IIIX", "marks": 223, "percentage": 59 }
  ]
};
const {name, id} = data;
const response = data.education
  .reduce((result, education) => ([...result, {name, id, education}]), []);

console.log(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newData = data.education
               .map(e => ({ id: data.id, name: data.name, education: e}))
```